# How to get input from console in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I began to use QT-creator to write C++ code, and I want to use std::cin to get input from console. However, even I check the 'project -> run in the terminal' and run my project, the terminal pops up but didn't wait for my input. There is one line in my terminal: press <RETURN> to end the program. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to check in order to have the std::cin command working:

- In the Projects tab, under Run settings, check the box "Run in terminal" (that you already did)
- Under Tools, Options, Environment, System, check that the "Patch command" path is correct (for me, it's `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`)
- Add the following two lines to your .pro file:

  `TEMPLATE = app`

  `CONFIG += console`
- Run qmake on your project then rebuild

After that, it should now be working, you can test with this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Your name is " << name << endl;
}
```